# Uniqueness of Taylor expansion?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, taylor-expansion

I am struggling with proof of Morse's lemma in my textbook.

**The context you need to know:**

Function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^3$.

It has nondegenerate critical point at $x=0$. $f(0)=0$

**Now what happened.**
In the proof we managed to represent our function $f$ the following way:

$$
f(x) = x^T \cdot H(x) \cdot x
$$

Where $H(x)$ is **symmetric** (can be viewed as a quadratic form at each point $x$)  $m \times m$ matrix. Every entry of $H(x)$ is a $C^1$ function of $x$.

Now they tell "*since the uniqueness of a Taylor expansion and continuity of entries of $H(x)$ we can conclude that $H(0)=\textbf{H}_f(0)$* "

($\textbf{H}_f$ denotes hessian matrix of the function $f$).

This "conclusion" actually strikes me out. Let's look at the Taylor's expansion of a function $f$ near $x=0$:
$$
f(x)-f(0) = x^T \cdot \nabla f(0) + x^T \cdot \textbf{H}_f(0) \cdot x + o(||x||^2)
$$
And since $f(0)=0$ and $\nabla f(0)=0$(critical point) we now can rewrite $f(x)$ as:
$$
f(x)=x^T \cdot \textbf{H}_f(0) \cdot x + o(||x||^2)
$$
Compare it with earlier result:

$$
f(x) = x^T \cdot H(x) \cdot x
$$

Does it straightly follows that $H(0)=\textbf{H}_f(0)$? I think "the uniqueness of Taylor expansion" is not applicable here since $x^T \cdot H(x) \cdot x$ is not a polynomial function of coordinates of $x$.

**UPDATE**

As I understood, we need to show that this condition

$$
x^T \cdot (H(x) - \textbf{H}_f(0)) \cdot x = o(||x||^2) \quad \text{as} \space x \to 0
$$

implies $H(0) = \textbf{H}_f(0)$

Comment: Since $H(x)$ is $C^1$, expanding the entries to first order helps. :)